# Using css scale transformation and panning scrollers - Positioning issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I am creating a zoom in and panning area for a web image tool, and I have managed to work the zoom feature, and the panning functionality works as well. I have ran into two issues though; - Firstly, when I pan, the panning position resets. Secondly, The scrolling feature doesn't allow me to access the left and top areas of my workspace area. Here is a codepen link to get an idea at what the issue is:

[Link to Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdBpmd?editors=011)

Code snippets:

Zoom Code:

```
function zoomIn() {
    $('#ui_container').css("zoom", "2");
}

function zoomOut() {
    $('#ui_container').css("zoom", "1");
}
```

Panning Code:

```
var curXPos = 0;
var curYPos = 0;
var curDown = false;
window.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
    curDown = true;
    curXPos = e.pageX;
    curYPos = e.pageY;
});
window.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
    curDown = false;
});
window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    if (curDown === true) {
        $('#ui').scrollLeft((document.body.scrollLeft + (curXPos - e.pageX)));
        $('#ui').scrollTop((document.body.scrollTop + (curYPos - e.pageY)));
    }
});
```

My code can also be found on the codepen. I have tried to fix this issue for a few hours now, but no result has been found. What can I do to fix this?

Thanks in advance, Ryan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out for my solution

```js
function zoomIn() {

  $('#ui_container').css("zoom", "2");

}

function zoomOut() {
  $('#ui_container').css("zoom", "1");
}

  var cX = 0;
  var cY = 0;
var dX=0;
var dY=0;

{ // Panning
  var cD = false;

  $("#ui_container").on("mousedown", function(e) {
    cD = true;
    cX = e.screenX;
    cY = e.screenY;
  });

  $("#ui_container").on("mouseup", function(e) {
    cD = false;
   cX=0;
   cY=0;
  });

  $("#ui_container").on("mousemove", function(e) {
    if (cD === true) {
     
     dX+=document.body.scrollLeft + (cX - e.screenX);
     dY+=document.body.scrollTop + (cY - e.screenY);
         cX = e.screenX;
         cY = e.screenY;

      $('#ui').scrollLeft(dX);
      $('#ui').scrollTop(dY);

    }

  });

}
```

```css
#ui {
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#ui_container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -200px;
  margin-top: -150px;
  background-color: #f0f;
  zoom: 1;
 background-image: url("http://www.clker.com/cliparts/x/u/9/2/j/G/transparent-square-hi.png");
 background-size: 10px 10px;
}

#ui_container_padding {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 padding: 20px;
 margin-left: -20px;
 margin-top: -20px;
}

#zoomIn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  background-color: #313131;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#zoomOut {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 26px;
  background-color: #313131;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ui">

  <div id="ui_container">
   
   <span id="ui_container_padding"></span>
 
 </div>

</div>

<span id="zoomIn" onclick="zoomIn()">+</span>
<span id="zoomOut" onclick="zoomOut()">-</span>
```

Comment: Press "Run code snippet" button to up side here ( blue one at the left) and try ! Its working.

Comment: I have tried that, but it's not showing the top left corner of the pink workspace...

Comment: its becouse of your class. if you set left and top values you can see :)